# Iterar un bucle y restar las fechas para obtener diferencias

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Estoy intentando restar dos fechas en bucle con el módulo datetime, pero no consigo resolver o aplicar la lógica. Actualmente lo que tengo hecho es esto:

```
import datetime
lista = [datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 37, 57, 912000), datetime.datetime(
2019, 4, 11, 0, 34, 46, 903000), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 6, 1, 53, 55, 751000)]

for x in lista:
    print(x)
```

Esto me devuelve algo del estilo:

```
Output >>>
2019-04-11 00:37:57.912000
2019-04-11 00:34:46.903000
2019-04-06 01:53:55.751000
```

Lo que quiero conseguir de forma dinámica es restar el valor nuevo por el anterior, algo del estilo:

```
date = (2019-04-11 00:34:46.903000 - 2019-04-06 01:53:55.751000)
```

He hecho pruebas y me ha funcionado esto (pero estático):

```
date1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 37, 57, 912000)
date2 = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 34, 46, 903000)
print(date1-date2)
```

La salida me devuelve esto:

```
Output>>>
0:03:11.009000
```

Cualquier ayuda servirá! Un saludo,

Gracias.

Comment: En la lista tienes 3 fechas, ¿quieres que primero haga date1 - date2 y el resultado restarle el date3? o ¿quieres restarle a la primera fecha la segunda y a la segunda la tercera?

Comment: Buenas @Raider mi idea es que se vaya restando con la fecha que entre nueva, ya que la lista va creciendo. (recojo los valores de una api)

Comment: Entonces, ¿la lista tendrá siempre 2 valores (la que había y la nueva que entre)? me resulta algo confuso, si la lista tiene, por ejemplo, 10 valores el último ¿a cual hay que restarlo?¿al antepenúltimo? ¿al primero? ¿a cada uno?

Comment: @Raider Si, la idea seria restar siempre el último valor con el previo a este, para obtener la diferencia de tiempo. Ejemplo: lista = [1,2,3], la lista se actualiza, lista = [1,2,3,4]. La idea es restar los valores 3, y 4. El valor último y el anterior al último.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un simple ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer lo que quieres, manteniendo la idea de restar fechas tal como indicas en el ejemplo.

Como puedes ver es simplemente recorrer la lista mediante índices, exceptuando el ultimo índice, para que no nos dé un error de índex out of range, vamos restando la fecha en el índice actual - la fecha un índice por delante. Así hasta completar el bucle.

Como indico más abajo esto es algo simple y no contempla otros posibles errores que ya verás ^^.

```
import datetime


def main():

    lista = [
            datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 37, 57, 912000), 
            datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 11, 0, 34, 46, 903000), 
            datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 6, 1, 53, 55, 751000)
            ]

    for i in range(len(lista)-1):
        print(lista[i]-lista[i+1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Es la solución mas basica, sin contemplar casos como que la lista tenga solo un elemento, etc.

Comment: favor de leer [answer], si bien este código soluciona el problema, siempre se pide no solo el script sino además explicarlo; por favor edita y mejora tu aporte

Answer (score 1):

En base a lo que hablamos en los comentarios, una solución podría ser la siguiente

```
diferencia = lista[-2] - lista[-1]
```

`-1` hace referencia al último valor y `-2` al penúltimo

El resultado del print, tal y como tienes la lista sería:

> 4 days, 22:40:51.152000

Comment: Gracias! Un saludo :)